# Braintree Drop-in - Submit form after the user has chosen a payment method

Tags: javascript, braintree

is there a way to automatically submit the form after the user has chosen a payment method with the Braintree Drop-in?
The problem is that the user is asked to choose a payment method, then press Ok, then again Ok, then press the actual Checkout button on my page.
It is a very weird behavior.

Here's the code I use to create the Drop-In.

```
<script>
    var form = document.querySelector('#payment-form');
    var nonceInput = document.querySelector('#nonce');

    braintree.dropin.create({
        authorization: '{{ $client_token }}',
        container: '#dropin-container',
        paypal: {
            flow: 'vault',
            currency: 'EUR',
            buttonStyle: {
                color: 'blue',
                shape: 'rect',
                size: 'medium'
            }
        },
        card: {
            cardholderName: true
        }
    }, function (err, dropinInstance) {
        if (err) {
            // Handle any errors that might've occurred when creating Drop-in
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }

        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            dropinInstance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
                if (err) {
                    // Handle errors in requesting payment method
                    return;
                }

                $.fancybox.open({
                    src  : '#processing-loading',
                    type : 'inline',
                    opts : {
                        toolbar: false,
                        buttons: false,
                        smallBtn: false
                    }
                });

                // Send payload.nonce to your server
                nonceInput.value = payload.nonce;
                form.submit();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: One way you can do this is listen for the `paymentMethodRequestable` event to fire, and when the [paymentMethodIsSelected](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web-drop-in/docs/current/Dropin.html#on-examples) is true, you can autosubmit the nonce. Please note that this will only apply for stored payment methods.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a go.